# Transform geometry to coordinates

Tags: postgis, geometry, coordinates

I need transform with postgis a geometry of type

```
010600002031BF0D0001000000010300000001000000050000008FEF9C07089AFEC0B90A9856E87251410F355DB1B395FEC0DCCEADDCED72514194BE3130A693FEC0DFD23127D072514114797186FA97FEC094E0C313CB7251418FEF9C07089AFEC0B90A9856E8725141
```

to

```
-1.130497 37.995302,-1.128874 37.995732,-1.128153 37.994190,-1.129663 37.993819,-1.130497 37.995302
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to transform coordinates to another SRID, you will use [ST_Transform](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html):

```
SELECT
    ST_AsText(
         ST_Transform('010600002031BF0D0001000000010300000001000000050000008FEF9C07089AFEC0B90A9856E87251410F355DB1B395FEC0DCCEADDCED72514194BE3130A693FEC0DFD23127D072514114797186FA97FEC094E0C313CB7251418FEF9C07089AFEC0B90A9856E8725141'
   ::geometry,4326))
```

which produces:

"MULTIPOLYGON(((-1.12598881799973 37.9623844064892,-1.1253665455084 37.9625408936206,-1.12507150251677 37.9616992426904,-1.1256937750081 37.9615554420694,-1.12598881799973 37.9623844064892)))"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ST_AsText](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html) function to get the WKT representation of your geometry, this will return the coordinates in whatever projection you have. (You will only get the latitude and longitude if your data is stored in a Geographic Coordinate system, SRID 4326 works for most cases)

You can use this query to change SRID

```
ALTER TABLE table 
   ALTER COLUMN geom 
   TYPE Geometry(MultiPolygon, 4326) 
   USING ST_Transform(geom, 4326);
```

And get the cordinates with:

```
 
select ST_AsText(geom)
from table
```